# How to remove unwanted characters from SQLite insert in android studio

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I was passing data from my server via JSON. I have got this error.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "rusitha": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO customer (id, name,nic,areaId,tp,address) VALUES ('583', 's.p.m.j.ilangasinghe.', '805250666v','18','0716090398','no.79,'rusitha',nuwarapara,maradankadawala.');
```

This is the code that I used.

```
for(i = 0;i<customerId.length();i++){
    sqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO customer (id, name,nic,areaId,tp,address) VALUES ('"+customerId.get(i).toString()+"', '"+customerName.get(i).toString()+"', '"+customerNIC.get(i).toString()+"','"+customerAreaId.get(i).toString()+"','"+customerTp.get(i).toString()+"','"+customerAddress.get(i).toString()+"');");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `'no.79,` doesn't have a closing single quote.This is because **rushita** is enclosed in single quotes and is preceeded by a comma. In short the address is not being escaped properly so the single quotes around rushita are confusing SQLite.

Your options are to either replace the single quotes in the address with 2 single quotes e.g.

```
customerAddress.get(i).toString().replace("'","''")
```

Or to let this be done on your behalf by using bindings by using  the extended signature [execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method. e.g

```
sqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO customer (id, name,nic,areaId,tp,address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"), newString[]{customerId.get(i).toString(),customerName.get(i).toString(),customerNIC.get(i).toString(),customerAreaId.get(i).toString(),customerTp.get(i).toString(),customerAddress.get(i).toString()});
```

- binding would be recommended over the previous method.

An alternative would be to use the [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) convenience method e.g

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("id",customerId.get(i).toString());
cv.put("name",customerName.get(i).toString());
cv.put("nic",customerNIC.get(i).toString());
cv.put("areaId",customerAreaId.get(i).toString());
cv.put("tp",customerTp.get(i).toString());
cv.put("address",customerAddress.get(i).toString());
long insertedId = sqlite.insert("customer",null,cv);
```

- This would be the most recommended way.

  - It builds the SQL on your behalf,
  - binds the values,
  - returns the rowid of the inserted row
  - and as it binds the values it, like the extended execSQL, protects against SQL injection.

Note the above code is in-principle code and has not been checked, tested or run, so there may be some small errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can escape Character  properly  for the JSON data you got before using them:

```
// JSON Escape Utility
public static String crunchifyJSONEscapeUtil(String crunchifyJSON) {
    final StringBuilder crunchifyNewJSON = new StringBuilder();

    // StringCharacterIterator class iterates over the entire String
    StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator(crunchifyJSON);
    char myChar = iterator.current();

    // DONE = \\uffff (not a character)
    while (myChar != StringCharacterIterator.DONE) {
        if (myChar == '\"') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\\"");
        } else if (myChar == '\t') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\t");
        } else if (myChar == '\f') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\f");
        } else if (myChar == '\n') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\n");
        } else if (myChar == '\r') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\r");
        } else if (myChar == '\\') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\\\");
        } else if (myChar == '/') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\/");
        } else if (myChar == '\b') {
            crunchifyNewJSON.append("\\b");
        } else {

            // nothing matched - just as text as it is.
            crunchifyNewJSON.append(myChar);
        }
        myChar = iterator.next();
    }
    return crunchifyNewJSON.toString();
}
```

[code originally from this site](https://crunchify.com/escape-character-utility-for-url-and-json-data-free-to-use-in-your-project/)